# Error: The metadata store replica is already in use in custom provider

Tags: metadata, microsoft-sync-framework

I install two instances of the same windows service on one server. Windows service uses SyncOrchestrator and two custom providers to synchronize data. Custom providers use SqlMetadataStore to store metadata. When I run one service, everything is fine, however, when one service is synchronizing, and i try to run second service, second service fails with message "The metadata store replica is already in use" in this.metadataStore.GetSingleReplicaMetadata().

Is this normal behavior? Does that mean that only one instance of SqlMetadataStore can be open/used at a time, regardless that metadata files are completely different?

Are there any workarounds? Do I have any other options?

Comment: are you sure they're pointing to separate metadata files? you normally get that error with concurrent sync using the same metadata file

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The services are in separate folders and I can see separate sdf files created. I can guess that the problem might be in assembly name, as both services have the same assembly name, but installed as separate windows service instances (I am using TopShelf for that). I'll try to test if that's the case.